# Predicting with lm object in R - black box paradigm

Tags: r

I have a function that returns an lm object.  I want to produce predicted values based on some new data.  The new data is a data.frame in the exact format as the data passed to the lm function, except that the response has been removed (since we're predicting, not training).  I would expect to execute the following, but get an error:

```
predict( model , newdata )
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ModelResponse' not found"
```

In my case, ModelResponse was the name of the response column in the data I originally trained on.  So just for kicks, I tried to insert NA reponse:

```
newdata$ModelResponse = NA
predict( model , newdata )
Error in terms.default(object, data = data) : no terms component nor attribute
```

Highly frustrating!  R's notion of models/regression doesn't match mine: 1. I train a model with some data and get a model object.  2. I can score new data from any environment/function/frame/etc. so long as I input data into the model object that "looks like" the data I trained on (i.e. same column names).  This is a standard black-box paradigm.

So here are my questions:
1. What concept(s) am I missing here?
2. How do I get my scenario to work?
3. How can I get model object to be portable?  str(model) shows me that the model object saved the original data it trained on! So the model object is massive.  I want my model to be portable to any function/environment/etc. and only contain the data it needs to score.

Comment: It's a "standard black box paradigm"?  You wouldn't happen to be working on a MBA, would you?

Comment: nope.  I'm not using "black-box" in the sense that "I have no idea what's happening inside" (I know what lm does).  I mean the paradigm of training a model with some data, and then being able to score the model with some new data and having it be as simple as that.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that produces the error?

Comment: Okay, so you're throwing around buzzwords.  There's something wrong with your code because R's "black box paradigm" works the way you describe (there is an example in `?predict.lm`).

Comment: are you using `predict` directly, or is it inside a wrapper function? some code and data would be useful to see what is going on

Comment: I'm working-up an example right now.  Will post when complete.

Comment: I wonder if you are being hit by the standard non-standard evaluation rules, and the environment of the formula. The fact that you have a function that is creating and returning an lm is what worries me. As usual, reproducible example code will no doubt help.

Comment: @Gavin my money is on the same thing, an issue with the environment of the formula, on account of a wrapper function that returns the lm object

Comment: All - apologies but I can't reproduce this.  In a simplified example, R scores just fine.  In my real code, R now scores just fine.  I'm baffled because I don't think anything has changed (but clearly something has =)  I'll keep this question open for a little while and see if I can reproduce the error...but it seems I was mistaken about lm().

Comment: Correction...one thing has changed: the data I'm training on.  My code randomly samples 50% of a dataset.  So perhaps the rows I choose at random caused the issue?  Seems doubtful.

Comment: Do you have factor variables in your regression? If you use a random sample of your data to calibrate and a different random sample to train, and if there is a missing factor level, you might get in trouble.

Comment: Ramnath - I have no factor variables, but good guess!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of str() on either the model or the data offered to the model, here's my guess regarding this error message:

```
predict( model , newdata )
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ModelResponse' not found"
```

I guess that you made a model object named "model" and that your outcome variable (the left-hand-side of the formula( in the original call to lm was named "ModelResponse" and that you then named a column in newdata by the same name. But what you *should* have done was leave out the "ModelResponse" columns (because that is what you are predicting) and put in the "Model_Predictor1", Model_Predictor2", etc. ... i.e. all the names on the right-hand-side of the formula given to lm()

The coef() function will allow you to extract the information needed to make the model portable.

```
mod.coef <- coef(model)
mod.coef
```

Since you expressed interest in the rms/Hmisc package combo `Function`, here it is using the help-example from ols and comparing the output with an extracted function and the rms `Predict` method. Note the capitals, since these are designed to work with the package equivalents of `lm` and `glm(..., family="binomial")` and `coxph`, which in rms become `ols`, `lrm`, and `cph`.

```
> set.seed(1)
> x1 <- runif(200)
> x2 <- sample(0:3, 200, TRUE)
> distance <- (x1 + x2/3 + rnorm(200))^2
> d <- datadist(x1,x2)
> options(datadist="d")   # No d -> no summary, plot without giving all details
> 
> 
> f <- ols(sqrt(distance) ~ rcs(x1,4) + scored(x2), x=TRUE)
> 
> Function(f)
function(x1 = 0.50549065,x2 = 1) {0.50497361+1.0737604* x1- 
   0.79398383*pmax(x1-0.083887788,0)^3+ 1.4392827*pmax(x1-0.38792825,0)^3-  
   0.38627901*pmax(x1-0.65115162,0)^3-0.25901986*pmax(x1-0.92736774,0)^3+ 
   0.06374433*x2+ 0.60885222*(x2==2)+0.38971577*(x2==3) }
<environment: 0x11b4568e8>
> ols.fun <- Function(f)
> pred1 <- Predict(f, x1=1, x2=3)
> pred1
  x1 x2     yhat    lower    upper
1  1  3 1.862754 1.386107 2.339401

Response variable (y): sqrt(distance) 

Limits are 0.95 confidence limits
# The "yhat" is the same as one produces with the extracted function
> ols.fun(x1=1, x2=3)
[1] 1.862754
```

(I have learned through experience that the restricted cubic-spline fit functions coming from rms need to have spaces and carriage returns added to improve readability. )

Comment: When I was getting the error (I can't reproduce it now), I did exactly as you said - I left out "ModelResponse" and I had my predictors in newdata.  It seems that predict() works fine even if I have NA ModelResponse column in newdata.  I'll need to repro the issue to help us dig deeper.  Is there a way to score with coef() without calculating the linear formula by-hand?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "by hand". Constructing a function that includes the coef values would work (if we were given more specifics) and the rms/Hmisc packages provide a `Function` (function) that extracts the model results in a manner that is useful. Not sure if it works with regular `lm()` derived objects though.

Comment: "by hand" I mean doing the matrix math to score new data given coefficients (although the operation is pretty easy).  The nice thing about predict() is that it does that for you.  I didn't quite understand your comment about the rms/Hmisc Function (function).  Is there an example you can point me to?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the error then it doesn't seem worth a lot of effort trying to guess what happened ... the general paradigm for prediction at one level down is `model.matrix(formula) %*% coef(model)`, but it's better to use `predict` if you can ...

Comment: DWin - very cool.  ols.fun is a significantly smaller object than f.  It seems regular lm is not supported (although there's probably a package that adds support).  This is a good tool to have in the toolbox.

Comment: Ben - how can I extract formula from an lm object so I can compute model.matrix(formula) %*% coef(model)?

Answer (score 2):

Thinking long-term, you should probably take a look at the `caret` package.  Many or most modeling functions work with data frames and matrices, others have a preference, and there may be other variations of their expectations.  It's important to quickly get your head around each, but if you want a single wrapper that will simplify life for you, making the intricacies into a "black box", then `caret` is as close as you can get.

As a disclaimer: I do not use `caret`, as I don't think modeling should be a be a black box.  I've had more than a few emails to maintainers of modeling packages resulting from looking into their code and seeing something amiss.  Wrapping that in another layer would not serve my interests.  So, in the very long-run, avoid `caret` and develop an enjoyment for dissecting what's going into and out of the different modeling functions.  :)

Comment: Iterator - AWESOME!  I'm looking forward to digging deeper into this package.

Comment: Be sure to see my updated warning.  :)   There is a compromise associated with using `caret`.  In my case, I can't or won't (yet) make that compromise.

Comment: noted! thanks.  Likely I'll follow your lead...I deal with data.frames and matrices and its easy to convert between and I haven't had issues with the various modeling packages (save this issue).  With all the packages available on CRAN, its always good to get a specific recommendation, even if its just to collect ideas.